# Use port from a service in a docker compose file into another service in a different docker compose file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, port, docker-network

I have 2 docker compose files as shown below. I want to use port 5432 from `db` service into `server` service. I have grouped both services into single shared network `custom_network`. `db` service exposes port `5432` but service `server` is unable to access this port.

I cannot create port mapping `5432:5432` in `server` because that port is already mapped in `db`

**file1.yaml**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: library/postgres:13-alpine
    container_name: local-dev-db
    depends_on:
      cloudsql-proxy:
        condition: service_started
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432  # host port:container port
    expose:
      - 5432
    networks:
      - custom_network
networks:
  custom_network:
    name: custom_network
```

**file2.yaml**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  server:
    image: custom:latest
    container_name: django-runserver
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ../:/code/project
    working_dir: /code/project
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py runserver"
    networks:
      - custom_network
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    # network_mode: host  # works on Linux, not mac
networks:
  custom_network:
    external:
      name: custom_network
```

Comment: Do you want to acces to postgres from the local-dev-server?

Comment: yes I want access db from server

Comment: What host and TCP port have you configured the application container to use for its database connection?  What error do you get?  If these two parts go together, can you run them in the same `docker-compose.yml`, deleting all of the manual `networks:` configuration?

Comment: You right @DavidMaze. I did not suggest the use of docker compose, but it the best and practical solution

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, i would try to check the connection between server and db.

For this purpose, i did some changes: removed some dependency (`cloudsql-proxy` you don't provided) and modified the image with `nginx` for the server (it's just a running random image to test the connection)

**file1.yaml**

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: library/postgres:13-alpine
    container_name: local-dev-db
    # depends_on:
    #   cloudsql-proxy:
    #     condition: service_started
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432  # host port:container port
    expose:
      - 5432
    networks:
      - custom_network
networks:
  custom_network:
    name: custom_network
```

In file2, as said, i set nginx image:

**file2.yaml**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  server:
    
    #image: custom:latest
    image: nginx
    container_name: django-runserver
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ../:/code/project
    working_dir: /code/project
    # removed this 
    #command: bash -c "python3 manage.py runserver"
    networks:
      - custom_network
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    # network_mode: host  # works on Linux, not mac
networks:
  custom_network:
    external:
      name: custom_network
```

No changes to network and volumes.

**Let's try to test the postgres reachability from the `local-dev-server` container**

Starting the compose:

`docker compose up -f file1.yaml file2.yaml --build --force-recreate --remove-orphans`

After start go into the `local-dev-server` with bash:

`docker exec -it django-runserver bash`

Install a Postgres client:

`apt update && apt install -y postgresql-client`

Test the connection to Postgres:

`pg_isready  -h local-dev-db  -p 5432 -U postgres`

In my case the response to this command was:

```
local-dev-db:5432 - accepting connections
```

**Then the db is accessible from the `django-runserver` container.**

Finally, you can use this approach in your real container.

If the db is not reachable the result should be something like this:

```
local-dev-ddb:5432 - no response
```

In this case, try to remove `cloudsql-proxy` and recheck.

Hope it helps!

Cose belle!